# Importing multiple files as a single module?

Tags: python, module, package

I have been chasing my tail for the last 4 hours here and can't find the solution.

I have the following module/package structure for my project.

```
.
├── app-cli.py
├── tools
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── adapters
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── cli.py
│   │   ├── web.py
│   ├── utils
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── core.py
│   │   │   ├── my_public_method()
│   │   ├── io.py
│   │   │   ├── some_other_public_method()
```

What I'm trying to do is bundle everything inside `utils` within the `utils` name space.

So when I do `import tools` at the main level, I can access the util functions as:

```
tools.utils.my_public_method()
tools.utils.some_other_public_method()
```

Instead of:

```
 tools.utils.core.my_public_method()
 tools.utils.io.some_other_public_method()
```

I have been editing the `__init__.py` messing around with the levels of imports, attempting to create a shortcut but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `__init__.py` inside the `utils` package you can add

```
from .core import my_public_method
from .io import some_other_public_method
```

and then you can do:

```
import tools.utils

tools.utils.my_public_method()
tools.utils.some_other_public_method()
```

Comment: Is there a way to do `from .core import *` and `from .io import *` so that I can have the `__all__` inside `core.py` and `io.py`?

Comment: Yes, you just need to change `from .core import my_public_method` with `from .core import *`

Comment: Ah yes, it works. For some reason `flake8` was not happy with the `from .core import *` bit. But it works. I guess I don't need the `__all__` bit inside the `utils/__init__.py` file.